# How to register a custom TaskChannel definition in Twilio?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am trying to register a custom `TaskChannel` that will query some service and add attributes to the task based on the result. At first glance in the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/task-channel-definition-api#registering-custom-channels-2), the process seems fairly straight-forward. It says:

> You must register your channel definitions before Flex starts up.

So if registering it from a plugin won't work, where should I register it from? Where do I put this code?

```
const myChannel = Flex.DefaultTaskChannels.createChatTaskChannel("myChannel",
    task => {
        task.attributes.myAttribute = "test"
    }
);

Flex.TaskChannels.register(myChannel);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are doing there is registering the TaskChannel in the Flex UI. However, you also need to create the TaskChannel definition in the "back-end" (TaskRouter).

This documentation on creating a TaskChannel via the TaskRouter API should be helpful: https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/task-channel#create-a-taskchannel

Comment: Okay, so I can only (re)define an existing task channel? If so, where do I put this code?

Comment: @Jezor I think the confusion here is that in Flex `createTaskChannel` really means adding a TaskChannel to the UI, not creating a brand new TaskChannel. You also need to have that TaskChannel created in TaskRouter before the UI knows what to do. It's up to you where that code lives - it could just be a setup script that you run once. If adding additional channels is part of your application's functionality, then you'd want a controller for it.